# Exponential distribution stochastic

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

Hi I don't know if this question makes sense but I hope someone could help me out.

The equations for exponential distribution in a poisson process is given as:

$P(T> \tau) = e^{-\lambda\tau}$ for $ \tau\geq0$

and $P(T\leq\tau) = 1 - P(T<\tau) = F(\tau)$

For all I know I use these two equations when solving for 'waiting times' kinda question but I am not clear about when to use which. I would assume $T$ to be the total time span. Can anyone help me clear my doubts?

Comment: If $T $ represents the time between two 'events', then you may want to know the probability that $T $ is greater than some number $t $ or you may wish to know the probability that $T$ is smaller than $t $. These are related as you have written in your question. So it is really up to you.

Comment: I didnt't get what you mean by 'its up to you'. Does it depend on how the question is asked? How should i picture it in a bus kinda question. e.g how long should the bus driver at most wait for the last passenger before he can depart with a full bus with a probability of 0.99. What would be the case here?

Comment: It does depend on the question.  If $T $ is the time it takes for the buss to be full, then we'd like to know the $Pr (T\leq t)=.99$ It is straightforward to find this $t$, for which I know that the probability that the bus is full is $.99$.